# Store Application Progress to Database

Tags: database, multithreading, progress-bar

I have a daily launched multi-threaded loading service. I would like to keep tack of the percentage progress of the loader. I was thinking that it would be good to have an update column on a database table that writes the %Progress. Is this a good idea or will there be a large overhead(5k updates per minute). Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The overhead in my opinion would be much too great, a much better solution would be to just keep the progress in memory on the server and make it available by exposing a request to a web service that would give you the current progress.

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail how this would work? A broad description please. My Web Service skills are a somewhat deficient!

Answer (score 1):

i agree with @scripni - expose the progress as a web service.  however, if you need to keep a log of the actual run, or the errors, then you can selectively store things like start time, any pertinent event, and end time in the database for later review. (jus try to avoid every single step of the process being posted)